# Create a dynamic time range in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

Is there a way to create a dynamic way to make a sql query that queries the data between the first day and the last day of every current month? I have a field called created and and I want to get the data where created is between the first day and the last day of the month.

Comment: Recursive CTE will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there a way to create a dynamic way to make a sql query that queries the data between the first day and the last day of every current month?

A simple method uses just date functions:

```
where created_at >= curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day and
      created_at < (curdate() + interval (1 - day(curdate()) day) + interval 1 month
```

In addition to only using date arithmetic, this doesn't have an error of missing the last second of the month.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will do it:

```
WHERE created BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(Now(), '%Y-%M-01 00:00:00') AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE_ADD(DATE_ADD(Now(),INTERVAL 1 MONTH), INTERVAL -12 HOUR), '%Y-%M-%d 23:59:59')
```

It’s not pretty, but it gets the job done.

Comment: @RakidNaomi . . . This is not an optimal solution because it can miss the last second of the month.